# KahaDBPersistenceAdapter and createQueueMessageStore

Tags: activemq-classic

I am not sure if I need to call createQueueMessageStore for each queue that will be persisted, and it not, what is the purpose of this call ? Is setting the adapter on the broker enough without individual queueMessageStores ?

Answer (score 0):

createQueueMessageStore() is used by the ActiveMQ Broker - you don't need to call this.

ActiveMQ automatically creates Queues and Topics on demand -

so if you send a message to a Queue foo.bar the ActiveMQ broker will check to see if it exists, and if it doesn't it will create it for you (using the createQueueMessageStore() call).